# About evaluation method of classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am still a beginner studying machine learning for the first time. I am dealing with problem of 4 class classification in my research. I would like to calculate accuracy, precision and recall. Since the number of data is small (about 30), the score is affected by how to be devided into train-set and test-set. When cross validation is executed, the variance is large.(For example accuracy is [0.83333333 0.72727273 0.44444444]) I am at a loss for evaluating this classifier. In such a case, do I perform cross validation 100 or 500 times and calculate mean of the validation scores? It is a very rudimentary question and bad English, I want you to answer this question.

```
ava = []
avp = []
avr = []
estimators = [("MinMaxScaler", MinMaxScaler()), 
              ("SVC", SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight='balanced', 
                C=1, decision_function_shape='ovr'))]
pl = Pipeline(estimators)

for i in range(ITER):       
    accuracy = cross_val_score(pl, X, y, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True))
    precision = cross_val_score(pl, X, y, scoring='precision_macro', cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True))
    recall = cross_val_score(pl, X, y, scoring='recall_macro', cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True))
    ava.append(np.mean(accuracy))
    avp.append(np.mean(precision))
    avr.append(np.mean(recall))
print("cross-val-score accuracy {}times average: ".format(ITER), np.mean(ava), "\n")
print("cross-val-score precision {}times average: ".format(ITER), np.mean(avp), "\n")
print("cross-val-score recall {}times average: ".format(ITER), np.mean(avr), "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to SO!

30 samples is indeed tiny data. Instead of k-fold CV, consider doing [leave-one-out CV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html) where you train your model `n` times on `n-1` samples, and test on one sample each time. Aside from calculating metrics, you would be able to see which samples your model gets wrong and why.

If your model is deterministic, there will be no affect of running more folds than samples.

In any case, try to think of ways to increase the size of your dataset either manually or synthetically.